# How do I split characters from a string in C++?

Tags: c++

For example, if I want to separate "A123456789" into 10 different strings or as integers, How would I do it?

Like:

```
T129542154
```

into:

```
String s = T
int 1=1
int 2=2
int 3=9
int 4=5
int 5=4
int 6=2
int 7=1
int 8=5
int 9=4
```

I have Googled, but most of them are separating words from a phrase, or having some special characters to separate instead of separating individual characters.

Comment: You can index `std::string` objects with the `[]` operator.

Comment: You can use  std::regex   and extract all patterns from your string.

Comment: could yall give me an example? I am not really good at C++... haven't write code for over half year...

Comment: Do you know in advance where the strings are and where the integers are, or is that part of the problem?

Comment: `A123456789` you reading this from a file or char array or string ?

Comment: @UmarFarooq I'll get this number through std::cin. its going to be same format, which is 10 characters and the start is an english letter

Comment: do you know `std::vector` ? or i jus post the answere without std::vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the input string is exactly 10 characters, consisting of a letter followed by 9 digits, you can very easily separate the individual characters into variables, eg:

```cpp
std::string input = "T129542154";
std::string s(input, 0, 1);
int i1 = input[1] - '0';
int i2 = input[2] - '0';
int i3 = input[3] - '0';
int i4 = input[4] - '0';
int i5 = input[5] - '0';
int i6 = input[6] - '0';
int i7 = input[7] - '0';
int i8 = input[8] - '0';
int i9 = input[9] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is something like this

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

std::string s = "S124822854"; // 1 letter, followed by 9 digits
char letter = s[0];
int digits[9];
std::transform(s.begin() + 1, s.end(), digits, [](char ch){ return ch - '0'; });
```

This uses an array to hold the integers (you could easily use `std::vector` or `std::array` instead).

Comment: its a bit complicated... still trying to understand it... through, thank you for helping me!

Comment: @陳柏睿 Just realised the code was wrong, see the fixed code above (I added `+ 1` to the last line).

Answer (score -1):

```
    int length = s.size();
    vector<int> sint, vector<char> schar; vector<int> whatitis;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
       if(s[i]>='0' && s[i]<='9'){
       sint.push_back(s[i]-'0');
       whatitis.push_back(1);
       }
       
       else{
       schar.push_back(s[i]);
       whatitis.push_back(2);
       }
    }

int one=0, two=0;
for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
if(whatitis[i]==1)
cout<<sint[one++];
else
cout<<schar[two++];
}
```

Comment: i'll try it later... it seems a bit complicated for me, at least. anyways, thank you for the help!

Comment: please add some explanations!

Comment: In first loop, we traversed over the whole string and checking whether the current character is a numerical else alphabetical and accordingly we pushed this information in whatitis array. In second loop, we use the stored information of whatitts array and then print accordingly.